# SQLite insert or ignore and return original _rowid_

Tags: python, sqlite

I've spent some time reading the SQLite [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html), various questions and answers here on Stack Overflow, and [this thing](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Keeping-ROWID-for-INSERT-OR-REPLACE-td34237.html), but have not come to a full answer.

I know that there is no way to do something like `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo VALUES(...)` with SQLite and get back the rowid of the original row, and that the closest to it would be `INSERT OR REPLACE` **but that deletes the entire row and inserts a new row and thus gets a new rowid**.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    data TEXT
);
```

Right now I can do:

```
sql = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
# create database
sql.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo(data) VALUES(?);", ("Some text.", ))
the_id_of_the_row = None
for row in sql.execute("SELECT id FROM foo WHERE data = ?", ("Some text.", )):
    the_id_of_the_row = row[0]
```

But something ideal would look like:

```
the_id_of_the_row = sql.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE foo(data) VALUES(?)", ("Some text", )).lastrowid
```

**What is the best (read: most efficient) way to insert a row into a table and return the rowid, or to ignore the row if it already exists and just get the rowid?** Efficiency is important because this will be happening quite often.

**Is there a way to `INSERT OR IGNORE` and return the rowid of the row that the ignored row was compared to?** This would be great, as it would be just as efficient as an insert.

Comment: Did you try `UPDATE ... WHERE ...`?

Comment: BTW, someone proposed that `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ... RETURNING` or some variant should return the original value: https://sqlite.org/forum/info/6b14076446260538 but the feature ws declined. RETURNING is a new addition as of sqlite 3.35: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html and returns selected data but only if the `INSERT` works. Similar question for PostgreSQL, also no solution yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way that worked the best for me was to `insert or ignore` the values, and the `select` the rowid in two separate steps. I used a `unique` constraint on the `data` column to both speed up selects and avoid duplicates.

```
sql.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo(data) VALUES(?);" ("Some text.", ))
last_row_id = sql.execute("SELECT id FROM foo WHERE data = ?;" ("Some text. ", ))
```

The `select` statement isn't as slow as I thought it would be. This, [it seems](https://web.archive.org/web/20121111205122/http://web.utk.edu/%7Ejplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html#indexes), is due to SQLite automatically creating an index for the `unique` columns.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT OR IGNORE` is for situations where you do not care about the identity of the record; where the goal is only to have *some* record with that specific value.

If you want to know whether a new record is inserted or not, you have to check by hand:

```
the_id_of_the_row = None
for row in sql.execute("SELECT id FROM foo WHERE data = ?", ...):
    the_id_of_the_row = row[0]
if the_id_of_the_row is None:
    c = sql.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO foo(data) VALUES(?)", ...)
    the_id_of_the_row = c.lastrowid
```

As for efficiency: when SQLite checks the `data`column for duplicates, it has to do exactly the same query that you're doing with the `SELECT`, and once you've done that, the access path is in the cache, so performance should not be a problem. In any case, it  *is* necessary to execute two separate `INSERT`/`SELECT` queries (in either order, both your and my code work, but yours is simpler).