# Postgres upsert: distinguish between new and updated rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I'm thinking of using PostgreSQL `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT UPDATE` functionality. Ideally I would be able to distinguish between which rows were successful inserted and which were updated. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You need an additional auxiliary column for this.

Comment: Using such functionality I can't see a way to have this information, as said by Klin, you would need a column to store which operation happened even with this you would need another thing to know that specific operation (because it can have many happening at same time). Best way I can see is to have a trigger with an audit table. The trigger would audit inserts and updates but even with a trigger you would need something to identify that operation to differentiate from the previous ones

Comment: There is a `RETURNING` clause for the insert command, but I would not know if it has the ability to distinguish between inserts and updates. See it here: [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a way without adding a column to your table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id int PRIMARY KEY, col int);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, 1);
```

```
INSERT INTO tbl(id, col)
VALUES (1,11), (2,22)
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET    col = EXCLUDED.col
RETURNING *, (xmax = 0) AS inserted;
```

Explanation:

- [Detect if the row was updated or inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878027/detect-if-the-row-was-updated-or-inserted/40880200#40880200)

Due to race conditions under concurrent write load, certain rows might not be returned. See:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional auxiliary column for this (`updated` in the example).

```
create table test (id int primary key, str text, updated boolean);
insert into test values (1, 'old', false);

insert into test values
    (1, 'new 1', false),
    (2, 'new 2', false)
on conflict (id) do
update set 
    str = excluded.str, updated = true
returning *;

 id |  str  | updated 
----+-------+---------
  1 | new 1 | t
  2 | new 2 | f
(2 rows)
```

Comment: How would he differentiate the newly updated=true from the previous conflicts (from another inserts/updates)? That is why I didn't provide such answer.

Comment: No need to distinguish between old and new conflicts as you have results from `returning *` which are always up-to-date.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't think of that. Thanks for the info.