# Detect if the row was updated or inserted

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, upsert

I am doing an `INSERT` with `ON CONFLICT` to postgres using java. Is there any way to find out if the `executeUpdate` inserted the row or updated it?

Comment: See [Postres upsert: distinguish between new and updated rows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38614358/1995738).

Comment: Unfortunately I can not edit the existing table, so that would not solve the problem.

Comment: If you're not updating on conflict (i.e. `DO NOTHING`) you can just check the updated row count. It will be 0 if there was a conflict.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can look at the [system column **`xmax`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) to tell the difference. It's `0` for inserted rows in this case.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id int PRIMARY KEY, col int);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, 1);
```

```
INSERT INTO tbl(id, col)
VALUES (1,11), (2,22)
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET    col = EXCLUDED.col
RETURNING *, (xmax = 0) AS inserted;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GIwCbUi1)

This is building on an undocumented implementation detail that might change in future releases (even if highly unlikely). It works for Postgres 9.5 all the way up to Postgres 15.

The beauty of it: you do not need to introduce additional columns.

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Upsert differentiate inserted and updated rows using system columns XMIN, XMAX and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058213/postgresql-upsert-differentiate-inserted-and-updated-rows-using-system-columns-x/39204667)