# How to distinguish conflict in sqlalchemy INSERT…ON CONFLICT (Upsert)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I was reading the documentation of SqlAlchemy regarding the upsert operation on postgres dialect at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert

Is there a way to know if the upsert has been an insert or an update?

The documentation seems to omit this detail.

Comment: is the insert on conflict inserting/updating a single row at a time, or rows in batches?

Comment: one row at a time

Comment: I think when you `execute` an upsert statement the returned value is of type `ResultProxy` with this you can use `is_insert` method to check if the `execute`d statement has inserted data or not - [RESULT_PROXY](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy). I am not able to confirm this as i dont use postgress database.

Comment: I saw the `ResultProxy.is_insert()` but I am not sure if it applies to the `postgresql.dml.insert()`

Comment: @Sanandrea, `is_insert` is a property not a method (so you can't call it), and `res_proxy.is_insert` will return true if the statement is an insert statement, so unfortunately will not help for this case, as it will return `true` even if an update is performed.

Comment: @HaleemurAli thank you, just a lapsus on the property, but I cannot modify the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a final `RETURNING` clause with:

```
...
RETURNING (tbl.xmax = 0) AS inserted
```

Returns `true` for inserted rows and `false` for updated rows. This relies on an undocumented implementation detail, though. For a detailed explanation see:

- [Detect if the row was updated or inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878027/detect-if-the-row-was-updated-or-inserted/40880200#40880200)
- [Differentiate inserted and updated rows in UPSERT using system columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058213/postgresql-upsert-differentiate-inserted-and-updated-rows-using-system-columns-x/39204667#39204667)

Adding OIDs (like suggested in another answer) adds cost, bloats the table and burns OIDs (if your table isn't trivially small). That's why the general setting of `default_with_oids` has been changed to `off` a long time ago (Postgres 8.1). [The manual for Postgres 11:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-DEFAULT-WITH-OIDS)

> The use of OIDs in user tables is considered deprecated, so most
> installations should leave this variable disabled. Applications that
> require OIDs for a particular table should specify `WITH OIDS` when
> creating the table.

Later versions even removed the setting `default_with_oids` completely.

Comment: Thank you, I am accepting yours as (apart from the deprecation reason and bloating) the effort is way lower than migrating the table schema.

Comment: Do note that it builds on an implementation detail that may change in future releases (*after* pg 11).

Comment: *undocumented implementation detail* is this safe for production? This seems more like a hack at a first glance.

Comment: It works reliably in all current versions, but while it's not documented, it may change in future major versions (though unlikely).

Comment: I see, ...together with the fact that is postgresql only functionality, I might as well not use it at all in the first place since all the unit tests in the project are on sqlite.

Comment: @Sanandrea: Aside: It's a fundamentally flawed idea to test projects supposed to run on Postgres with SQLite. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278943/939860

Comment: my experience going along with this unfortunate setup is the same as what you are suggesting, but there is still the fear that once we abandon the standard SQL expressions we might not be RDBMS agnostic from the application point of view. Thank you again!

Comment: Nitpicking: Being "RDBMS agnostic" is a false goal. Impossible, even, since there is no RDBMS in existence that's even close to the SQL standard. (And the standard has pretty weak spots.) Postgres is probably the closest among the big ones. Still a valid idea to prefer SQL standard ways where possible. OK, we are dragging this out. I think we both got the point.

Answer (score 4):

From the postgresql documentation on [insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.146.7):

> On successful completion, an INSERT command returns a command tag of the form
>
> ```
> INSERT oid count
> ```
>
> The count is the number of rows inserted or updated. If count is exactly one, and the target table has OIDs, then oid is the OID assigned to the inserted row. The single row must have been inserted rather than updated. Otherwise oid is zero.

Thus it is possible to check for updates vs inserts by examining the query message

A table can be created with `OIDs` using syntax

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (...) WITH OIDS
```

, or `OIDs` may be enabled on an existing table with syntax

```
ALTER TABLE mytable SET WITH OIDS
```

Using sqlalchemy, a table may be created using `OIDs` as follows:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert as pg_insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@hostname:port/db')

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    __table_args__ = {'postgresql_with_oids': True}
    email = sa.Column(sa.Text, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Text, nullable=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

And the insert on conflict statement may be constructed like this:

```
p = {'email': 'hal@hal.hal', 'name': 'Hally hal'}
stmt = pg_insert(Person).values(p)
stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements = [Person.email],
    set_ = {'name': stmt.excluded.name}
)
```

finally, once the statement is executed, a result proxy is returned, which has a property `lastrowid` that corresponds to the `oid` in the query message `INSERT oid count`

Thus, if you execute `stmt` the first time

```
r = engine.execute(stmt)
```

`r.lastrowid` will output `an integer > 0` since a new row is created

Every other time, `r.lastrowid` will output `0`.

---

If you need to track upsert of multiple rows at a time, you can set up extra columns as flags that are updated from the on conflict do update portion of your insert statement.

There are many ways to do this, depending on the exact requirements. Here's is 1 alternative.

add an extra column `conflict_updated_at = sa.Column(sa.Datetime(True))`

change the upsert defintion to

```
stmt = pg_insert(Person).values(p)
stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements = [Person.email],
    set_ = {'name': stmt.excluded.name,
            'conflict_updated_at': sa.func.now()}
)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! Do you know a way by any chance if the `on_conflict_do_update` code can be somehow tested with sqlite dialect? My unit tests are all in sqlite and up to now I have used only standard SQL expression. I have used `with_variant` on some data types, but do not know a way to do it with operations.

Comment: it wouldn't work as sqlite doesn't have an upsert mechanism as postgresql does. for this test, your only route is to use a postgresql database. Here's a great answer that deals with configuring postgresql for such usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407442/optimise-postgresql-for-fast-testing/9407940#9407940