# Weird now() time difference with Postgres triggers

Tags: postgresql, transactions, timestamp, sequelize.js, plpgsql

In a Postgres 10.10 database, I have a table `table1` , and an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on `table1` for `table2`:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    -- other cols
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table1_pkey ON table1(id int4_ops);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    table1_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES table1(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    -- other cols (not used in query)
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table2_pkey ON table2(id int4_ops);
```

This query is executed on application start:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_insert_table1()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 (table1_id, ..., created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (NEW.id, ..., 'now', 'now');
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert_table1 ON "table1";

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_table1
AFTER INSERT ON "table1"
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_insert_table1();
```

I noticed some `created_at` and `updated_at` values on `table2` are different to `table1`. In fact, `table2` has mostly older values.

Here are 10 sequential entries, which show the difference jumping around a huge amount within a few minutes:

```
|table1_id|table1_created            |table2_created               |diff            |
|---------|--------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------|
|2000     |2019-11-07 22:29:47.245+00|2019-11-07 19:51:09.727021+00|-02:38:37.517979|
|2001     |2019-11-07 22:30:02.256+00|2019-11-07 13:18:29.45962+00 |-09:11:32.79638 |
|2002     |2019-11-07 22:30:43.021+00|2019-11-07 13:44:12.099577+00|-08:46:30.921423|
|2003     |2019-11-07 22:31:00.794+00|2019-11-07 19:51:09.727021+00|-02:39:51.066979|
|2004     |2019-11-07 22:31:11.315+00|2019-11-07 13:18:29.45962+00 |-09:12:41.85538 |
|2005     |2019-11-07 22:31:27.234+00|2019-11-07 13:44:12.099577+00|-08:47:15.134423|
|2006     |2019-11-07 22:31:47.436+00|2019-11-07 13:18:29.45962+00 |-09:13:17.97638 |
|2007     |2019-11-07 22:33:19.484+00|2019-11-07 17:22:48.129063+00|-05:10:31.354937|
|2008     |2019-11-07 22:33:51.607+00|2019-11-07 19:51:09.727021+00|-02:42:41.879979|
|2009     |2019-11-07 22:34:28.786+00|2019-11-07 13:18:29.45962+00 |-09:15:59.32638 |
|2010     |2019-11-07 22:36:50.242+00|2019-11-07 13:18:29.45962+00 |-09:18:20.78238 |
```

Sequential entries have similar differences (mostly negative/mostly positive), and similar orders of magnitude (mostly minutes vs mostly hours) within the sequence, though there are exceptions

Here are the top 5 largest positive differences:

```
|table1_id|table1_created            |table2_created               |diff            |
|---------|--------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------|
|1630     |2019-10-25 21:12:14.971+00|2019-10-26 00:52:09.376+00   |03:39:54.405    |
|950      |2019-09-16 12:36:07.185+00|2019-09-16 14:07:35.504+00   |01:31:28.319    |
|1677     |2019-10-26 22:19:12.087+00|2019-10-26 23:38:34.102+00   |01:19:22.015    |
|58       |2018-12-08 20:11:20.306+00|2018-12-08 21:06:42.246+00   |00:55:21.94     |
|171      |2018-12-17 22:24:57.691+00|2018-12-17 23:16:05.992+00   |00:51:08.301    |
```

Here are the top 5 largest negative differences:

```
|table1_id|table1_created            |table2_created               |diff            |
|---------|--------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------|
|1427     |2019-10-15 16:03:43.641+00|2019-10-14 17:59:41.57749+00 |-22:04:02.06351 |
|1426     |2019-10-15 13:26:07.314+00|2019-10-14 18:00:50.930513+00|-19:25:16.383487|
|1424     |2019-10-15 13:13:44.092+00|2019-10-14 18:00:50.930513+00|-19:12:53.161487|
|4416     |2020-01-11 00:15:03.751+00|2020-01-10 08:43:19.668399+00|-15:31:44.082601|
|4420     |2020-01-11 01:58:32.541+00|2020-01-10 11:04:19.288023+00|-14:54:13.252977|
```

Negative differences outnumber positive differences 10x. The database timezone is UTC.

`table2.table1_id` is a foreign key, so it should be impossible to insert before insert on `table1` completes.

`table1.created_at` is set by Sequelize, using option `timestamps: true` on the model.

When a row is inserted into `table1`, it's done inside a transaction. From the documentation I can find, triggers are executed inside the same transaction, so I can't think of a reason for this.

I can fix the issue by changing my trigger to use `NEW.created_at` instead of 'now', but I'm curious if anyone has any idea what the cause of this bug is?

Here is the query used to produce the above difference tables:

```
SELECT
    table1.id AS table1_id,
    table1.created_at AS table1_created,
    table2.created_at AS table2_created,
    (table2.created_at - table1.created_at) AS diff
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2   ON 
    table2.table1_id = table1.id AND (
        (table2.created_at - table1.created_at) > '2 min' OR 
        (table1.created_at - table2.created_at) > '2 min')
ORDER BY diff;
```

Comment: 'now' is not a timestamp, it is a string. Try using the function now(). But to your direct question you you can new.created_at from the table1 row.

Comment: They're the same: `SELECT 'now'::timestamp = now();`. Aware I can use `NEW.created_at`, was asking about the root cause for this

Comment: 1. Are you sure, neither table receives **updates**? You can identify inserted rows by looking at `xmax`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40880200/939860 2. Are there any other *triggers*  on table `table1` that might interfere? 3. Does the target column list of your `INSERT`have the same number of elements as the `VALUES` list?

Comment: Generally, please show the verbatim, complete trigger and trigger function definitions and *always* your version of Postgres. Also, the error may be in the query used to join `table1` and `table2` to inspect the diff. We'd really need to see query and table definitions. All in all, this is a case for a crystal ball ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've added the requested details above

Comment: @BenedictLewis: You delivered and provided everything to make this a useful and interesting question now.

Comment: @Belayer: You were on the right track. `SELECT 'now'::timestamp = now();` returns `true`. Both are still not "the same".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While **`'now'`** is not a plain string, it is also not a function in this context, but a ***special date/time input***. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE)

> ... simply notational shorthands that will be converted to ordinary date/time values when read. (In particular, `now` and related strings are converted to a specific time value as soon as they are read.)

The body of a PL/pgSQL function is stored as string, each nested SQL command is parsed and prepared when control reaches it the first time *per session*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING)

> The PL/pgSQL interpreter parses the function's source text and
>   produces an internal binary instruction tree the first time the
>   function is called (within each session). The instruction tree fully
>   translates the PL/pgSQL statement structure, but individual SQL
>   expressions and SQL commands used in the function are not translated
>   immediately.
>
> As each expression and SQL command is first executed in the function,
>   the PL/pgSQL interpreter parses and analyzes the command to create a
>   prepared statement, using the SPI manager's `SPI_prepare` function.
>   Subsequent visits to that expression or command reuse the prepared statement.

There is more. Read on. But that's enough for our case:

The first time the trigger is executed ***per session***, `'now'` is translated to the current timestamp (the transaction timestamp). While doing more inserts in that same transaction, there won't be any difference to `transaction_timestamp()` because that is stable within a transaction by design.
But every subsequent transaction in the same session will insert the same, constant timestamp in `table2`, while values for `table1` may be anything (not sure what Sequelize does there). If new values in `table1` are the then current timestamp, that results in a "negative" diff in your test. (Timestamps in `table2` will be older.)

### Solution

Situations where you actually want <strike>`'now'`</strike> are few and far between. Typically, you want the function **`now()`** (without single quotes!) - which is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (standard SQL) and `transaction_timestamp()`. Related (recommended reading!):

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

In your particular case I suggest [**column defaults**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html) instead of doing additional work in triggers. If you set the same default `now()` in `table1` and `table2`, you also eliminate any nonsense the `INSERT` to `table1` might add. And you never have to even mention these columns in inserts any more:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    -- other cols
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()   -- or leave this one NULL?
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    table1_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES table1(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    -- other cols (not used in query)
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),  -- not 'now'!
    updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()   -- or leave this one NULL?
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_insert_table1()
  RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table2 (table1_id)  -- more columns? but not: created_at, updated_at
   VALUES (NEW.id);                -- more columns?

   RETURN NULL;                     -- can be NULL for AFTER trigger
END
$$;
```