# Returning old row values in UPSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, common-table-expression, upsert

I have the following table in Postgres 14:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id            text PRIMARY KEY
, top           bigint  NOT NULL
, top_timestamp bigint  NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to upsert `top` and `top_timestamp` while returning the old values (if any). If the row already exists, I want to update it only if the new value of `top` is > old value.

The solution also HAS to account for concurrent writes.

For the upsert, I have this so far:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
AS mt (id, top, top_timestamp)
VALUES ('some-id', 123, 999)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET top=123, top_timestamp=999
WHERE mt.top < 123
```

I realise that `RETURNING` can only refer to new values, so to return the old values, I have this:

```
WITH old_values AS (
   SELECT top, top_timestamp FROM mytable
   WHERE id = 'some-id' FOR UPDATE
   )
, upd AS ($upsertSqlAbove)
SELECT top AS old_top, top_timestamp AS old_top_timestamp
FROM old_values;
```

This seems to work, but is it safe for concurrent writes?
Does `SELECT FOR UPDATE` work as I expect here? Namely, it will lock the row until the whole query is finished?

What is the difference between that first query and this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
AS mt (id, top, top_timestamp)
VALUES ('some-id', 123, 999)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET top=123, top_timestamp=999
WHERE mt.top < 123
RETURNING (SELECT top FROM mytable WHERE id = 123) AS last_top, 
          (SELECT top_timestamp FROM mytable WHERE id = 123) AS last_top_timestamp
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kHcydiYbDZ8RABa2fDsZ5/2) to test.

Comment: Thanks, clarifies some details. In my fiddle, I stuck to the simplified version in the question with just integer values. Works the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's the issue?

You ask:

> What is the difference between that first query and this:

Either reports old values from the last row version that has just been updated in a concurrency-safe manner. But the first one is more expensive. It locks an existing row earlier. So it holds the lock for longer and possibly blocks concurrent writes to the same row for longer. It also executes one more statement. Most importantly, it locks the row even when no later `UPDATE` happens, which is a complete waste.

So the 2nd query is better. Except for two flaws:

1. It runs a separate `SELECT` for every column. That would seem necessary since a subquery expression in the `RETURNING` clause can only return a single value.
2. It runs those `SELECT` queries even after an `INSERT`. Then the `SELECT` is guaranteed to come up empty - at full cost.

#### Return the old row only if updated

Unfortunately, the `UPDATE` part of an UPSERT does not allow additional tables in a `FROM` clause - unlike regular `UPDATE`. See:

- [Return pre-UPDATE column values using SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only/7927957#7927957)

So your attempts are well-founded.

This query fixes both flaws (tested in Postgres 14 & 16):

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl AS t (id, top, top_timestamp)
VALUES ('some-id', 123, 999)
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET    top = EXCLUDED.top                      -- !
     , top_timestamp = EXCLUDED.top_timestamp  -- !
WHERE  t.top < EXCLUDED.top                    -- !
RETURNING (SELECT t_old FROM tbl t_old
           WHERE  t_old.id = t.id
           AND    t.xmax <> 0                  -- actually an UPDATE!
          ).*                                  -- !!!
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qKyyO31v)

(To clarify for the general audience: The subquery in the `RETURNING` clause operates on the same snapshot of the table and does not see any  row inserted or updated in the same statement, yet. It sees the old row version.)

The test `t.xmax <> 0` filters actual updates. See:

- [Detect if the row was updated or inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878027/detect-if-the-row-was-updated-or-inserted/40880200#40880200)

And we can circumvent the discussed restriction for subqueries by returning a single (well-known) row type, and *then* [de-composing it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) - with **`(`** `SELECT ...` **`).*`**.

Plus, use the special row variable `EXCLUDED`. It holds the row proposed for insert, and helps to avoid spelling out input values repeatedly. (Subtle difference: all default values and triggers have already been applied.)

This returns the whole row. To only return selected columns, what the UPSERT in a CTE and decompose later:

```sql
WITH ups AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl AS t (id, top, top_timestamp)
   VALUES ('some-id', 124, 1000)
   ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
   SET    top = EXCLUDED.top
        , top_timestamp = EXCLUDED.top_timestamp
   WHERE  t.top < EXCLUDED.top
   RETURNING (SELECT t_old FROM tbl t_old
              WHERE  t_old.id = t.id
              AND    t.xmax <> 0
             ) AS t_old
   )
SELECT id, top , top_timestamp  -- just the columns you want
FROM  (SELECT (t_old).* FROM ups) sub;
```

Note how I decompose the row type in a subquery *once*. This is to avoid repeated evaluation. See:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-a-query/18370271#18370271)

#### Return the old row in any case

According to your comment, you even want the old row back if no update happens. If the `WHERE` condition is not true, no update happens and `RETURNING` does not return any rows. That's an even trickier combination of `SELECT`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` (UPSERT). Above query won't cut it. Your CTE solution would work. Or an empty update like used here:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/37543015#37543015)

Simple, but wasteful - as explained in my answer to the same question:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

Combine everything we have learned so far with this:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

To arrive at this optimized function for **single-row UPSERT**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_upsert_tbl(_id text, _top bigint, _top_timestamp bigint, OUT old_row tbl)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      SELECT *
      FROM   tbl
      WHERE  id = _id
      AND    top >= _top   -- new value isn't bigger
      INTO   old_row;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;

      INSERT INTO tbl AS t
             ( id,  top,  top_timestamp)
      VALUES (_id, _top, _top_timestamp)
      ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
      SET    top = EXCLUDED.top
           , top_timestamp = EXCLUDED.top_timestamp
      WHERE  t.top < EXCLUDED.top                    -- new value is bigger
      RETURNING (SELECT t_old FROM tbl t_old
                 WHERE  t_old.id = t.id
                 AND    t.xmax <> 0                  -- actually was an UPDATE!
                ).*
      INTO   old_row;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_upsert_tbl('some-id', 123, 999);
```

Or:

```
SELECT id, top FROM f_upsert_tbl('new-id', 3, 3);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iGYVOt3f)

`OUT old_row tbl` uses the registered row type of the table as "OUT" parameter. Replace with your actual (schema-qualified) table name.  Obviously, adapt all column names and types to your actual table definition.

Should be the **perfect solution**. Keeps locks to a minimum (doesn't write-lock at all, when just returning an old, unchanged row), and handles every corner case concurrent writes might produce in default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level. The call becomes super simple and short as demonstrated.

Possible downsides:

- Creates a dependency on the table type. If you modify table columns you may have to recreate the function. You can't drop the table unless you add `CASCADE` to the `DROP` command.
- Not for multi-row UPSERT.

Comment: Legend. Thank you. Really appreciate your time on this. I will go with the query you suggested. What does `xmax <> 0` and `.*` mean?

Comment: @msamyatl: There is a link in my answer explaining `xmax <> 0`. And `(<row_value>).*` decomposes a (well-known!) row type. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS

Comment: The query you provided is close to the requirements I've got. It currently does not return the previous value if the `WHERE t.top < EXCLUDED.top` condition fails. This is even the case if if remove the `xmax` condition. Is the CTE approach my only option then?

Comment: @msamyatl: I added another answer with a highly optimized solution. I should get paid for this. Well, it's the season ... :)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. This helps me understand the drawbacks of each approach very clearly so thank you for the DB lesson. And you should get paid for this -- what an absolute DB master. And I've been learning a lot from all your comments on SO. My production server is grateful for the optimized queries.