# Postgresql upsert return id on conflict?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query right now which returns the id after a successful insert

```
INSERT INTO match (match_id) values(?) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id
```

How can I make this return the `id` of the row which already exists on conflict?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/2996101), which states "do not update identical rows without need".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` instead to ensure that the query operates on a row and so can return something:

```
CREATE TABLE match(id serial PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO match (id) VALUES (1)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
  SET id = excluded.id
RETURNING id;
```

Comment: I get the following error "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name
  Hint: For example, ON CONFLICT (column_name).
  Position: 41"

Comment: Also I wanted to mention, it's `match_id` that I'm setting, and I want `id` returned

Comment: My bad, you have to specify what's conflicting -- I've edited. You can specify what you're updating and returning however you like, although unless `id` is based on `match_id` I'm not sure how you're going to trigger the conflict without explicitly specifying it in your insert.

Comment: The following works `INSERT INTO match (match_id) VALUES (33333)
ON CONFLICT (match_id) DO UPDATE
  SET match_id = excluded.match_id
RETURNING id;` however on every conflict my sequence increases. Is that supposed to happen? no way around it?

Comment: You could use a non-serial key like a UUID. Otherwise, serial ids are guaranteed to be unique, not to be contiguous. Gaps happen.

Comment: @arya, if you replace "excluded" with "match", it should return the existing id instead of incrementing it. This answer should be modified.

Comment: It might not be clear, but `excluded` is a "special" table that you only can access in `SET` and `WHERE` clauses of `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` statements.... Cool!  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT.