# Postgres: SELECT or INSERT in high concurrent write load DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, upsert, sql-returning

We have a DB for which we need a "selsert" (not upsert) function.
The function should take a text value and return a id column of existing row (SELECT) or insert the value and return id of new row (INSERT).
There are multiple processes that will need to perform this functionality (selsert)

I have been experimenting with `pg_advisory_lock` and `ON CONFLICT` clause for INSERT but am still not sure what approach would work best (even when looking at some of the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql) answers).

So far I have come up with following

```
WITH 
selected AS (
  SELECT id FROM test.body_parts WHERE (lower(trim(part))) = lower(trim('finger')) LIMIT 1
),
inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO test.body_parts (part)
  SELECT trim('finger')
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM selected )
  -- ON CONFLICT (lower(trim(part))) DO NOTHING -- not sure if this is needed
  RETURNING id
)
SELECT id, 'inserted' FROM inserted
UNION
SELECT id, 'selected' FROM selected
```

- Will above query (within function) insure consistency in high
  concurrency write workloads?
- Are there any other issues I must consider (locking?, etc, etc)

BTW, I can insure that there are no duplicate values of (part) by creating unique index. That is not an issue. What I am after is that SELECT returns existing value if another process does INSERT (I hope I am explaining this right)

Unique index would have following definition

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX body_parts_part_ux
  ON test.body_parts
  USING btree
  (lower(trim(part)));
```

Comment: Possible migration to [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Nah, this is about "programming" in SQL.

Comment: @Parfait  IMHO,  this is very much about programming, as it relates to how to write SQL that concurrent apps will use and SQL that is safe for high concurrent write workloads.

Comment: @zam6ak ... DBA SE does indeed allow programming but in a specialized vein. I recommend the migration because such concepts,  *consistency*, *high concurrency*, *locking* are DBA concepts, a bit more nuanced than general SQL scripting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/14731