# How to get returning values using executeBatch?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I need to insert a lot of rows but only unique rows *(it will take very long time to explain app architecture and why I can't make rows unique on Java side before inserting but in my case it's not an optimal way)*, my function is below:

```
private void addAttrNames(List<Attribute> attrs) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stmt = getSession().prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO public.attr_names (\"name\") VALUES (?) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id"
    );
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < attrs.size(); ++i) {
        Attribute attr = attrs.get(i);
        stmt.setString(1, attr.getAttrName().getName());
        stmt.addBatch();
        if (i % BATCH_SIZE == 0 || i == attrs.size() - 1) {
            stmt.executeBatch();
            ResultSet keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            while (keys.next()) {
                attrs.get(index++).setAttrNameId(keys.getLong(1));
            }
            keys.close();
        }
    }
    stmt.close();
}
```

**getSession().prepareStatement():**

```
public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    statement.setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE);
    return statement;
}
```

The problem is that `keys` is empty. I tried with and without `RETURNING id` part but it still doesn't work.

Is it possible to use batches with `ON CONFLICT` clause to return generated IDs?

**P.S.** I use PostgreSQL 11

Comment: Try `prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"id"})`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, unfortunately, it returns ID if row was inserted only. Seems PostgreSQL doesn't return ID if `ON CONFLICT` clause was executed.

Comment: That is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name although, I need to update existing values but that's ok for my task.

Comment: Be aware: support for `getGeneratedKeys` in batch execution is not required by the JDBC specification.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah, that's true but postgresql driver implements it