# PostgreSQL 11.6 ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT not triggering update, but constraint should be activated

Tags: postgresql, insert, upsert

I have a table created like so:

```
create table change.payer
(
    account_id text not null
        constraint payer_account_id_pk
            primary key,
    entity_identifier text,
    entity_type text,
    name text,
    contact_information jsonb,
    etin text,
    document_fetched_at timestamp,
    created_at timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
);
```

I upsert data to it, like so:

```
        INSERT INTO change.payer (
            "account_id", "entity_identifier", "entity_type", "name",
            "contact_information", "etin", "document_fetched_at"
            )
        VALUES (
            %(account_id)s, %(entity_identifier)s, %(entity_type)s, %(name)s,
            %(contact_information)s, %(etin)s, %(document_fetched_at)s
            )
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT payer_account_id_pk
        DO UPDATE SET
            entity_identifier = change.payer.entity_identifier,
            entity_type = change.payer.entity_type,
            name = change.payer.name,
            contact_information = change.payer.contact_information,
            etin = change.payer.etin,
            document_fetched_at = change.payer.document_fetched_at
        ;
```

For some reason when I write new rows with the same `account_id`, no updates happen.  I'm not sure exactly what is happening, 
1) i get no error
2) i know the data is changing because i insert every thing into a history table so i see data/timestamps change
3) no new rows are written

essentially, nothing changes in `change.payer` even as i attempt to upsert new data, but new rows are written to my history table.

Comment: `no updates happen` - to be precise: updates *do* happen, but columns are set to their current values. You still accrue most of the costs, triggers are still fired, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860 (You found the right fix using `EXCLUDED`.)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the right side of the set clause is not the table, you're inserting into, but the data you want to insert.  also, you must use a keyword `EXCLUDED`

so the correct upsert query for my use case would be:

```
        INSERT INTO change.payer (
            "account_id", "entity_identifier", "entity_type", "name",
            "contact_information", "etin", "document_fetched_at"
            )
        VALUES (
            %(account_id)s, %(entity_identifier)s, %(entity_type)s, %(name)s,
            %(contact_information)s, %(etin)s, %(document_fetched_at)s
            )
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT payer_account_id_pk
        DO UPDATE SET
            entity_identifier = EXCLUDED.entity_identifier,
            entity_type = EXCLUDED.entity_type,
            name = EXCLUDED.name,
            contact_information = EXCLUDED.contact_information,
            etin = EXCLUDED.etin,
            document_fetched_at = EXCLUDED.document_fetched_at
        ;
```