# For each row in table A, update A.amount related rows in table B

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, lateral-join

Using PostgreSQL 16.2, I have two tables:

`task_pool` table

```sql
create table task_pool (
  task_id serial primary key
, order_id integer
, user_id integer
, expire_time timestamp
, status integer default 0
);
```

Sample data:

| task_id | order_id | user_id | expire_time | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 80 | 1 | 2024-03-00 11:52:44 | -1(*expired*) |
| 51 | 81 | 1 | 2024-03-00 16:00:44 | -1 (*expired*) |
| 52 | 80 | 2 | 2024-04-19 12:31:22 | 0 (*active*) |
| 53 | 81 | 4 | 2024-03-00 16:52:44 | -1(*expired*) |
| 54 | 81 | 6 | 2024-03-00 16:51:44 | -1(*expired*) |

`reactivate_task` table *this table is actually a temporary table using WITH AS in a longer query, but for simplicity here is code to create the table:*

```sql
create table reactivate_task(
, order_id integer
, successfully_added
, total_amount_requested
, amount_to_reactivate integer
);
```

Sample data:

| order_id | successfully_added | total_amount_requested | amount_to_reactivate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 81 | 0 | 3 | 2 |

What I'm trying to do is, for each row in `reactivate_task`, update the `x` oldest expired tasks with the related `order_id`, and `x` being that row's `amount_to_reactivate`

So in the example tables above, looking at `reactivate_task` table, the 3 oldest expired tasks with order_id 80 should be "reactivated". And the 2 oldest expired_tasks with order_id 81 should be "reactivated".

There are the intended results in table `task_pool`:

| task_id | order_id | user_id | expire_time | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 80 | 1 | 2024-03-21 12:00:00 | 0(*active*) --status set to 0 and expire_time to current_timestamp |
| 51 | 81 | 1 | 2024-03-21 12:00:00 | 0(*active*) ----status set to 0 and expire_time to current_timestamp |
| 52 | 80 | 2 | 2024-04-19 12:31:22 | 0 (*active*) --NOT updated (even though amount_to_reactive was 3 for order_id 80, there was only ONE expired task (task_id 50) that was expired. |
| 53 | 81 | 4 | 2024-03-19 16:52:44 | -1(*expired*) --NOT updated (amount_to_reactive was only 2 for order 81, so only the 2 rows with oldest expire_time were updated (task_id 50 & 54) |
| 54 | 81 | 6 | 2024-03-21 12:00:00 | 0 (*active*) ----status set to 0 and expire_time to current_timestamp |

This is an example query for ONE row:

```sql
UPDATE task_pool 
SET status=0, 
    expire_time = current_timestamp + (2 * interval '1 day')
WHERE task_id IN (
    SELECT task_id
    FROM task_pool
    WHERE order_id = *--order_id from CURRENT ROW OF REACTIVATE_TASK--*
          AND status=-1 
    ORDER BY expire_time
    LIMIT *--amount_to_reactivate from current row of reactivate_task--*
```

But with this query I have to iterate over each row in `reactivate_task` outside of Postgres (I'm using node and node-postgres, using a for loop on the `results.rows[]`)

Is there a way to do this in Postgres in one query, instead of iterating over each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE task_pool t
SET    status = 0
     , expire_time = current_timestamp + (interval '2 days')
FROM   reactivate_task r
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT t1.task_id
   FROM   task_pool t1
   WHERE  t1.order_id = r.order_id
   AND    t1.status = -1
   ORDER  BY t1.expire_time
   LIMIT  r.amount_to_reactivate
   ) t1
WHERE t.task_id = t1.task_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c0Oyh2XH)

Basics for [`UPDATE` syntax in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

Identify the maximum number of candidate rows in a `LATERAL` subquery. See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Additional relations in the `FROM` clause to an update cannot join laterally to the target table, so you have to use a second instance of the same table in this special situation. Related:

- [Is there a way to set multiple column values on a single spatial query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550292/is-there-a-way-to-set-multiple-column-values-on-a-single-spatial-query/61568728#61568728)

`CROSS JOIN` eliminates rows from `reactivate_task` where no qualifying rows to activate can be found.

If `amount_to_reactivate` is null (which it probably should never be), there is effectively no limit.

If `(order_id, expire_time)` of `task_pool` is not `UNIQUE`, ties will be broken arbitrarily, unless you add more expressions to the `ORDER BY` to make it deterministic.

If there can be concurrent, competing writes on the table `task_pool` you may have to add a locking clause. But not in the same subquery, you'd add another subquery level above the one with the `LIMIT`. Related:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

Comment: Oh, sorry , the duplicate values was from copying/pasting. task_id will be primary key. 
amount_to_reactive will never be null as a previous query I have removes any null/0 results.
Thank you I will test this out now. trying to learn postgres but it is so confusing for me right now, expecially a cross join lateral!

Comment: Hmm. Ok I'm getting an error: 
`ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "t"
SQL state: 42P01
Detail: There is an entry for table "t", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

It may be have to do with the fact that the table **reactivate_task** is actually a tempory table, the result of a CTE in a longer query I have been trying to make (this post was the last part).  It doesn't have a primary key and has  two other columns, I had just assumed they were irrelvant so didn't include them. I will update and let me know if that's why the error occured.

Comment: To be clear: A temp table can be used just like a regular table here. Same goes for a CTE attached to the same query. And `reactivate_task` does not strictly need a PK. But duplicates in `reactivate_task.order_id` should be weeded out. Additional columns in `reactivate_task` don't matter for my query. My initial post had typos after I adapted it to your updates at the last moment (and no fiddle to test it, yet).

Comment: Ok, yes, this worked now!  Thank you!
I am still struggling to understand, but I will analyze your query and the explanation you wrote!
Ok, I figured a temp table would not matter, which is why at first I didn't go into it in the original post. 
Also There will not be any duplicates of reactivate_task.order_id :)