# Detect and signal onConflict with knexjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

This document [here](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-ignore) explains that using `onConflict()` and `ignore()` will simply drop the action quietly. If I am trying to insert a new row into a table as following:

```
const addItem = (item) => {
  return database(dbTable).insert(item)
                .onConflict('name')
                .ignore()
                .then(() => {
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
}
```

If instead of `ignoring`, how (or where) do I return some sort of signal to the external call that invokes the function `addItem`? For example, return `0` if no conflict (and item being added); return `1` if there is conflict (and the promise quietly resolved without doing anything)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be database dependent functionality, but for example if you do insert with postgres and it doesn't return any rows it means that there was conflict like mentioned in this issue:

[How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql)

Also `.returning('*')` seems to work correctly combined with `.onConflict(...).ignore()`

https://runkit.com/embed/6p825ex0xt4b

```
knex('table').insert({a: 1, b:2}).onConflict('id').ignore().returning('*').toSQL().sql;

// knex 0.21.15 returns: 
// insert into "table" ("a", "b") values (?, ?) 
//    on conflict ("id") do nothing returning *
```