# In UPDATE part of UPSERT, compute expression once for multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT (primary_key) DO UPDATE` query in a PostgreSQL 12 database.

It requires me to do the same calculation for multiple columns in the update clause. The calculation isn't too complex, but I would prefer not to maintain it in two places. The calculation contains a reference to both the conflicting row and to the `EXCLUDED` virtual table.

Is there any way to perform this calculation once and assign its result to a temporary variable within a single query expression?

The full query is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(id, refreshed_at, tokens) VALUES ('id', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 60)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
        tokens = GREATEST(
          -1, 
          LEAST(
            GREATEST(0, table_name.tokens) 
              + EXTRACT(epoch FROM EXCLUDED.refreshed_at) 
              - EXTRACT(epoch FROM table_name.refreshed_at), 
            100
          ) - 1
        ),
        refreshed_at = CASE 
          WHEN (
            GREATEST(0, table_name.tokens) 
              + EXTRACT(epoch FROM EXCLUDED.refreshed_at) 
              - EXTRACT(epoch FROM table_name.refreshed_at)
            ) > 0 THEN EXCLUDED.refreshed_at 
          ELSE table_name.refreshed_at 
          END
        RETURNING tokens >= 0;
```

The `tokens` column is calculated from the column's prior value the difference in seconds between the time of query and the last time the column was updated. The `refreshed_at` column should only be changed if the `tokens` column value was updated, so the same calculation has to be performed in both `SET` clauses.

Comment: Just show the statement (even if it's not working), and your version of Postgres.

Comment: If the calculation contains the conflicting row, how will you reuse the result of one calculation? Perhaps a function makes more sense?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Added. The query works fine but I would prefer not repeating it in case it needs to be updated later.

Comment: Parentheses don't seem to match. Also: data type of `refreshed_at`?

Comment: `refreshed_at` is a timestamp, `tokens` is an integer, `id` is text. I did lightly edit the query before pasting it in, so the parens may be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The refreshed_at column should only be changed if the tokens column value was updated

Your original idea should work with a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(id, refreshed_at, tokens)
VALUES ('id', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 60)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET    (tokens, refreshed_at)
     = (SELECT GREATEST(-1, LEAST(GREATEST(0, table_name.tokens) + sub.diff, 100) - 1)
             , CASE WHEN sub.diff > 0 THEN EXCLUDED.refreshed_at ELSE table_name.refreshed_at END
        FROM  (SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM EXCLUDED.refreshed_at - table_name.refreshed_at)::int) sub(diff))
RETURNING tokens >= 0;
```

That's an [allowed variant of the `UPDATE` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html). This way, the difference between timestamps in seconds is only calculated once.

The calculation is cheaper, too, extracting the epoch from the difference (the resulting `interval`):

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM EXCLUDED.refreshed_at - table_name.refreshed_at)
```

instead of extracting twice and subtracting like in your original:

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM EXCLUDED.refreshed_at) - EXTRACT(epoch FROM table_name.refreshed_at)
```

But the overhead from the added subquery may be more expensive than doing the cheap calculation twice!

#### Alternative solution

Consider adding a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE` part instead. Like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(id, refreshed_at, tokens)
VALUES ('id', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 60)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET     tokens = GREATEST(-1, LEAST(GREATEST(0, table_name.tokens) + EXTRACT(epoch FROM EXCLUDED.refreshed_at - table_name.refreshed_at), 100) - 1)
      , refreshed_at = EXCLUDED.refreshed_at
WHERE   EXTRACT(epoch FROM EXCLUDED.refreshed_at - table_name.refreshed_at)::int > 0
RETURNING tokens >= 0;
```

That would not touch rows at all where the time difference is below 1 second. That's typically superior because empty updates just add cost and bloat. (The cast *rounds*, you may want to *truncate* instead?)

Of course that would also not return a row where neither the `INSERT` nor the `UPDATE` part went through. If that's a problem, consider:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)