# MySQL/MariaDB: Is this the most efficient way to insert unique values and return nonunique values?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I had a statement in PSQL that did this just fine (based on an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/11117197) thread)
But I've been trying to recreate the same statement in MySQL which has been difficult. My current workaround is ugly:

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE potential_duplicates (
        id VARCHAR(64)
        content TEXT,
    
    ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
    INSERT INTO potential_duplicates(id, content) VALUES ('1', 'some content'), ('2', 'some more content');
    SELECT id, content FROM potential_duplicates WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM main_table);
    INSERT INTO main_table(id, content)
       SELECT id, content FROM potential_duplicates WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM main_table);
```

This query is going to be used very often and I feel like making a temporary table every query is inefficient. Originally I was trying to find a way to use the [`INSERT ON DUPLICATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature. It would have worked fine if I was just inserting and nothing else, but i need to return the duplicate values in the end.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? Which version?

Comment: @Nick using MariaDB 10.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `id` is a primary key (or at least unique), you can use `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid duplicates and [`RETURNING`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/) (available as of MariaDB 10.5) to return the inserted `id` values:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE main_content(id, content) 
VALUES ('2', 'some content'), ('5', 'some more content')
RETURNING id
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=b5063720609d6d9d271206c465c4bb61)

Comment: WOW this is so much better! I thought that the returning would return all values, but glad to know it doesnt

Comment: @VincentLauffer the docs say it returns the values from the "inserted" rows, but I agree its unclear whether they mean the rows that were actually inserted, or the ones in the insert.