# Why do I get an empty result in Postgres UPSERT with UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, conflict, upsert

Trying the following UPSERT in PG (nodejs):

```sql
WITH upsert_result AS(
    INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
    VALUES($1,$2)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM upsert_result
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1=$1
```

Why do I sometimes get empty results?

It is my understanding that the `UNION` here was supposed to prevent this by fetching the conflicting row.

Here is the table definition:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "ltree";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(
    col1 TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES table2 (col1) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    col2 ltree NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS tree_col2_idx ON table1 USING gist (col2);
```

I expected the query to return either the newly inserted row (if a row with same `col1` doesn't already exist) or the existing row (if a row with the same `col1` already exists). Indeed, this is what happens most of the time, but on some rare occasions, I get an empty result from the insert above.

Comment: if there is a conflict `on conflict do nothing` nothing will happen and thus no rows are returned afaik

Comment: to be sure of the expected behaviour, please provide some sample data and the exact expected results.

Comment: Add the table definition of `table1` to the question, including the constraint `ON CONFLICT` is referencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **hidden race condition**.

The check for conflicts includes (has to include!) rows from (yet) uncommitted concurrent transactions. If one has written to a row which your transaction now tries to UPSERT, your transaction has to wait for the other one to finish.

If the other transaction ends normally, your `INSERT` will detect a conflict and `DO NOTHING`, hence also not return the row. The `SELECT` sees the **same snapshot from the start of the query** and also cannot return the yet invisible row.

Read a detailed assessment here, especially chapter "Concurrency issue 1":

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

... and how to overcome it.

Aside: `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`. But that's also in the linked answer.

Comment: Does the UNION part occur after the other transaction (the concurrent insert) finishes? If so, why does it not see the updated snapshot?

Comment: @Marumba With defailt "READ COMMITTED" isolation level, like its name inicates, only what has been committed at the start of each command is visible. All CTEs together with the outer `SELECT` form a *single* command and cannot see row versions committed later. So while the `UNION` part chronologically happens after the other transaction has committed, what's written by that other transaction remains invisible until the next command is started. Follow the provided link for more details.