# How to ignore SequelizeUniqueConstraintError in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Using the example from the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-elements-of-a-hasmany-or-belongstomany-association), everything works well only at the first insertion. After the second and subsequent, errors appear.

```js
const Product = this.sequelize.define('Product', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING
});
const Tag = this.sequelize.define('Tag', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  unique: true
});
const ProductTag = this.sequelize.define('ProductTag', {
  product_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  tag_id: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

Product.belongsToMany(Tag, {through: 'ProductTag', as: 'tag'});
Tag.belongsToMany(Product, {through: 'ProductTag'});
```

The first insert works fine.

```js
Product.create({
  title: 'Chair',
  tag: [
    { name: 'Alpha'},
    { name: 'Beta'}
  ]
}, {
  include: [{
    model: Tag,
    as: 'tag'
  }]
})
```

SQL logs

```sql
INSERT INTO "Product" ("id","title","created_at","updated_at") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Chair','2019-02-25 12:51:50.802 +00:00','2019-02-25 12:51:50.802 +00:00') RETURNING *;
INSERT INTO "Tag" ("id","name","created_at","updated_at") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Alpha','2019-02-25 12:51:51.061 +00:00','2019-02-25 12:51:51.061 +00:00') RETURNING *;
INSERT INTO "Tag" ("id","name","created_at","updated_at") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Beta','2019-02-25 12:51:51.061 +00:00','2019-02-25 12:51:51.061 +00:00') RETURNING *;
INSERT INTO "ProductTag" ("product_id","tag_id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES (1,1,'2019-02-25 12:51:51.068 +00:00','2019-02-25 12:51:51.068 +00:00') RETURNING *;
INSERT INTO "ProductTag" ("product_id","tag_id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES (1,2,'2019-02-25 12:51:51.072 +00:00','2019-02-25 12:51:51.072 +00:00') RETURNING *;
```

Subsequent insertions `Product.create(...)` produce errors `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError`

`Key "(name)=(Alpha)" already exists.`

How to make it so that if the tag already exists, it took the ID of the existing one and ignore the error?

Comment: You've tagged this question as both [mysql] and [postgresql] - which RDBMS are you actually using?

Comment: You may want to look at [upsert](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert).

Comment: Use [postgresql]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @TGrif, but using upsert, only the product is added. Tags are not added.

Comment: What's the behaviour, because on your model definition you have tags as `unique: true`. That means that on your all records you can only have one of each value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Ellebkey. Yes, each tag is unique. But why sequelizejs does not take into account this condition? Instead of creating a new record, why doesn't it make upsert instead of create?

Comment: Because your including the tag model on the Product creation, there for you are creating also a new Tag.  And now I see that you defined a M:N relation so you should chekc [this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html) documentation.

Comment: I edit post. Yes, I have Product belongsToMany Tag, and Tag belongsToMany Product.

Comment: You can use findOrCreate function of Sequlize. But for this, you will be needing to separately do this operation after product is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution.

Add method `updateOrCreate`

```
Product.updateOrCreate = function (options) {
    return this.findOrCreate(options).then(res => {
        let [row, created] = res;
        if (created) return [row, created];
        return row.update(options.defaults, options.transaction)
            .then(updated => [updated, created]);
    })
};
Tag.updateOrCreate = function (options) {
    return this.findOrCreate(options).then(res => {
        let [row, created] = res;
        if (created) return [row, created];
        return row.update(options.defaults, options.transaction)
            .then(updated => [updated, created]);
    })
};
```

use

```
let data = {
    title: 'Chair',
    tag: [
        {name: 'Alpha'},
        {name: 'Beta'}
    ]
};
return sequelize.transaction().then(t => {
    return Product.updateOrCreate({
        where: {title: data.title},
        defaults: data,
        transaction: t
    }).then(res => {
        let [product] = res;
        return Promise.all(data.tag.map(tag => {
            return Tag.updateOrCreate({
                where: {name: tag.name},
                defaults: tag,
                transaction: t
            }).then(res => {
                let [tag] = res;
                return Promise.resolve(tag);
            }).catch(err => Promise.reject(err.message));
        })).then(() => {
            t.commit();
            sequelize.close();
        }).catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
    }).catch(err => {
        t.rollback();
        sequelize.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**`bulkCreate` with `ignoreDuplicates: true`**

This might be of interest. Tested on sequelize@6.5.1 sqlite3@5.0.2 this produces a single [`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql), and PostgreSQL produces `ON CONFLIC DO NOTHING`.

Note the problem of missing IDs further discussed below.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.' + path.basename(__filename) + '.sqlite',
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  },
});
(async () => {
const Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true,
  },
});
await sequelize.sync({force: true})
await Tag.create({name: 't0'})

// Individual create does not have the option for some reason.
// Apparently you're just supposed to catch.
// https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4513
//await Tag.create({name: 't0', ignoreDuplicates: true})

// SQLite: INSERT OR IGNORE INTO as desired.
// IDs may be missing here.
const tags = await Tag.bulkCreate(
  [
    {name: 't0'},
    {name: 't1'},
    {name: 't1'},
    {name: 't2'},
  ],
  {
    ignoreDuplicates: true,
  }
)
const tagsFound = await Tag.findAll({order: [['name', 'ASC']]})
assert.strictEqual(tagsFound[0].name, 't0')
assert.strictEqual(tagsFound[1].name, 't1')
assert.strictEqual(tagsFound[2].name, 't2')
assert.strictEqual(tagsFound.length, 3)

await sequelize.close();
})();
```

**Missing IDs problem**

The return value of `Tag.bulkCreate` does not contain the IDs generated by SQLite during `INSERT INTO` unfortunately however as mentioned at: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11223#issuecomment-864185973

This is likely because neither SQLite nor PostgreSQL return the row in the underlying queries:

- [SQLite insert or ignore and return original _rowid_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244393/sqlite-insert-or-ignore-and-return-original-rowid)
- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql)

This breaks the use case mentioned by OP of assigning tags to a product immediately from the return, because we would need the IDs for the through table.

I'm not sure how it compares to OPs `findOrCreate` option, but I think it will be faster to just do a second find/SELECT afterwards, on my Article has Tags model "update model" controller I went for:

```
  await Promise.all([
    req.app.get('sequelize').models.Tag.bulkCreate(
      tagList.map((tag) => {return {name: tag}}),
      {ignoreDuplicates: true}
    ).then(tags => {
      // IDs may be missing from the above, so we have to do a find.
      req.app.get('sequelize').models.Tag.findAll({
        where: {name: tagList}
      }).then(tags => {
        return article.setTags(tags)
      })
    }),
    article.save()
  ])
```

Comment: This is a GREAT workaround for most cases.